# How to copy a Linux file into a Windows PC?

Tags: linux, winscp

How do I copy files in others account in Linux to my Windows PC. I have [WinSCP](http://winscp.net/eng/index.php).

I’ve the access permission to other account (`sudo`).

Answer (score 0):

If you need to do that quite often, I would suggest opening a TFTP server on your Linux machine. Then using any TFTP client on your Windows machine you can push/pull files. It’s fast and easy to set up on both Linux and Windows.